# How do I find the last element of an array using recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

All I want is to make getLastElement(char[] array) which returns the last element of an array using recursion. This method can only access index 0 by using array[0].
I can use Arrays.copyOfrange.
I can only modify the code inside isSymmetric and the code inside getLastElement.

I already tried the following method to access index 0 but am having problems finding the last element of the array.

Code:

```
    public static char getLastElement(char[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length == 0)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        if(array.length == 1) {
            return array[0];
        } else {
            return getLastElement(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length));
        }
    }



    public static boolean isSymmetric(char[] array) {
        if (array == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Null argument.");

        if(array.length <= 1) return true;


        if(getLastElement(array) == array[array.length -1])


            return isSymmetric(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length-1));

        return false;
    }
}
```

I just want it to return the last element of the array and I want it to be able to only access array[0].

Comment: I understand this is a homework or learning exercise, but it's so absurd that it's appalling. In real life we would never use recursion to access the last element of an _array_, that's what indexes are for. Maybe if it were a _linked list_ I'd understand it. Teachers should stop making this nonsense questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 4th line of `isSymmetric` function there is a bug.
Change  `if(getLastElement(array) == array[array.length -1])` to `if(getLastElement(array) == array[0])`

Comment: You can only acces index 0

Answer (score 1):

Check this one :

```
    public static char getLastElement(char[] array) {
        //CANNOT be modified
        if (array == null || array.length == 0)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        //This code can be modified
        if(array.length == 1) {
            return array[0];
        } else {
            return getLastElement(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length));
        }
    }
```

If array has one element, we just return it. Otherwise we pass copy of array beggining at index 1 of previous array.

Comment: This is giving me errors. I'm going to add all the code and the output to see what it is.

Comment: I checked it on sample input array and it works, so there has to be something wrong with your code that is invoking that method.

Comment: I edited the post. The number of errors is 4 while it should be 0. I don't understand why it's wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char getLastElement(char[] array) {
    //CANNOT be modified
    if (array == null || array.length == 0)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    //This code can be modified 
    try{
        return getLastElement(Arrays.copyOfRange(array,1,array.length));
    }catch (NullPointerException ex){
        return array[0];
    }

}
```

It will not work for empty array - then null pointer will be throw but I guess tis OK. Ive assumed that You cannot use length of array for diffrent puropuse then copyOfRange

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would need to copy anything. Just increment the index on each recursion

```
public static char  getLastElement(char[] array) {  
   if(array == null) throw new RuntimeException("array should be initialized");  
   return getLastElement(array, 0);  
}

private static char getLastElement(char array, int index) {  
   if(index == array.size() - 1) {
      return array[index];
   }  
   return getLastElement(array, index + 1);
}
```